# How do I output a list of data in a specific order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Using Rails, I'm trying to display all of the 'fragments' in a given 'chapter', in the order of the 'print order' assigned to each fragment.

Here's what I'm using:

@chapter.fragments.order("printorder").each do |fragment|

And yes, this is all very, very new to me. :)
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? I'm not sure what print order is.

```
@fragments = @chapter.fragments.order("printorder desc")

@fragments.each do |fragment|
```